# Perl, ODBC, SQL server, Print messages returned in wrong order

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc

I use perl 5.16.3, DBD::ODBC 1.47, Unix ODBC 2.2.11, freeTDS 0.91

I create the small program below, run it and get the output:

```
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Third
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Second
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]First
```

Why is the lines in reverse order? I have set TDSDUMP and looking in the logfile it seems like the lines are send to me in the correct order.

The tested code is:

```
use strict;

use DBI qw(:sql_types);
use DBD::ODBC qw(:diags);

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:database", "USER", "SECRET");
$dbh->{odbc_err_handler} = \&ODBCMsgHandler;
$dbh->do("use asra_jkp" );

my $statement = "CREATE PROCEDURE testprint AS print 'First' print 'Second' print 'Third'";
$dbh->do($statement);

$statement = "EXEC testprint";
$dbh->do($statement);

$statement = "DROP PROCEDURE testprint";
$dbh->do($statement);

sub ODBCMsgHandler {
    my ($state, $msg, $native, $rc, $status) = @_;
    print "$msg\n";
}
```

EDIT:

I tried on another machine with perl 5.18.2 and DBD::ODBC 1.50. On this machine the print statements come in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself and leave an answer for others to find.

The problem is UnixODBC. Upgrading UnixODBC to the latest version (2.3.4) solved the problem.